# Vertical line for dhtmlxScheduler

Tags: php, javascript, css, dhtmlx

I am developing a scheduler using [dhtmlxScheduler library](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml). I need to add vertical line that shows current time. It's position should be updated every minute. I wonder if someone did something similar before. I googled for available solutions, but I haven't found any example yet. So, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

It can be enabled by

```
scheduler.config.mark_now = true;
```

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_mark_now_config.html

You will need to include ext/dhtmlxscheduler_limit.js to enable the above option.